# Incoherencia en resultado de query "isnull(columna,'') devuelve un espacio"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, tsql

Durante el proceso de producción de una solución en C# se guardaron registros formando un "folio" con una literal, un valor de celda y un id

```
'C'+ISNULL(Columna1,'')+Columna2
```

Ejemplo de resultado:

```
C96
CX85
```

Las consultas no han cambiado, se sigue usando el mismo motor de base de datos (MSSQL server 2008) pero ahora la misma consulta trae la siguiente diferencia:

```
'C'+ISNULL(Columna1,'')+Columna2
C 96
```

No entiendo por que `ISNULL(Columna1,'')` devuelve un espacio (ya me asegure que la columna efectivamente tenga `NULL`).
Se que se puede solucionar el problema agregando `LTRIM` o `RTRIM`, sin embargo quisiera saber el por que esto cambio.

Comment: No será que el resultado que está mostrando vienen de  Columna1 = null y  Columna2 = 96

Comment: Yo acabo de hacer la prueba en un SqlServer 2000 y 2008 y en ambos devuelve correctamente sin el espacio en blanco

Comment: Al igual que @Pikoh acabo de hacer un ejercicio y el resultado es el esperado. Seguramente estás pasando algo por alto. [Aquí puedes ver la prueba](http://rextester.com/NIAVQ25175)

Comment: @Flxtr tenia razón. Encontré una diferencia, la Columna1 en el periodo de pruebas fue creada siendo varchar(1), actualmente esta como nchar(1), al parecer esto hace la diferencia, a tal punto que si fuese nchar(10) y tuviera guardado un NULL, aun así el resultado arrojaría 10 espacios.

Comment: Sugiero que agregues la respuesta con lo que acabas de encontrar, seguramente a algún otro usuario le pasará en algún momento de la vida. Recuerda marcar tu respuesta como valida dentro de 48 hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la Columna1 en el periodo de pruebas fue creada siendo varchar(1), actualmente esta como nchar(1), esto haria la diferencia, a tal punto que si fuese nchar(10) y tuviera guardado un NULL, el resultado de esta consulta arrojaría 10 espacios:

```
'C'+ISNULL(Columna1,'')+Columna2
C          96
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando

`'C'+TRIM(ISNULL(Columna1,''))+Columna2`

Puede que efectivamente Columna1 tenga un espacio, o que Columna2 inicie con un espacio. En este segundo caso prueba con

`'C'+TRIM(ISNULL(Columna1,''))+TRIM(Columna2)`

Si sale bien, entonces una de las columnas tiene espacios.

Tambien intenta con la funcion CONCAT

`CONCAT('C',ISNULL(Columna1,''),Columna2)`

y si aun sale con espacios agregales TRIM al segundo y tercer parametro.

Comment: `concat` es una función que está disponible desde SQL Server 2012 en adelante

Comment: El OP dice _Se que se puede solucionar el problema agregando LTRIM o RTRIM, sin embargo quisiera saber el por que esto cambio_ Con lo que en realidad esto no provee una respuesta a la duda

Comment: y `TRIM` es una función de SQL Server 2017